# API calls for Hybrid Mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have some questions regarding hybrid mobile apps;

```
1. Is the final output of a hybrid app same as native app (.app for IOS, .apk for Android) ?
2. For a hybrid app, do we need 2-way communication between web portion and native portion of the app? I understand it would depend on the app, but am just asking a general question.
3. What kind of calls are needed between native / web portion of the app? e.g. I think one would be that web portion can tell the native portion that it has loaded. Can you list down some other examples ?
4. What is the role of a library like PhoneGap in a hybrid app ?
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1-. Is the final output of a hybrid app same as native app (.app for IOS, .apk for Android) ?

Yes, same as native

> 2-. For a hybrid app, do we need 2-way communication between web portion and native portion of the app? I understand it would depend on
>   the app, but am just asking a general question.

The phonegap/cordova API have 2-way communication, the web portion executes a JS method that calls a native method and the native method have a callback that executes a  JS method when it finish (or when it starts and continues executing the callback until it finish)

> 3- What kind of calls are needed between native / web portion of the
>   app? e.g. I think one would be that web portion can tell the native
>   portion that it has loaded. Can you list down some other examples ?

Anything that uses the phonegap/cordova API

> 4- What is the role of a library like PhoneGap in a hybrid app ?

It provides the API to execute native methods

You can check the phonegap/cordova API [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/index.html)

Comment: Thx for that...You said we have 2-way communication between web portion and native portion of the app ....And you also said that PhoneGap API provides API to execute native methods...So for hybrid app, is it always that the web portion (JS calling native method) would make a native call and we have a callback on the web side post response....But we do not have the other way round (native calling web portion) ?

Comment: Yes, native code can execute JS code on the cordova webview any time, on iOS you do it with [cordovaWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:"javascript here"];  and in java with cordovaWebView.loadUrl("javascript here");